# Google CSE - get the result title on a second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-custom-search

I've a problem with Google CSE code (i admit i also don't have much experience with javascript).

My problem is that I have to pass the title of the result to a second webpage, opened when clicking on a result title of my CSE

```
<div id="mysite_webResult">
  <div class="gs-webResult gs-result"
    data-vars="{longUrl:function() {
      var i = unescapedUrl.indexOf(visibleUrl);
      return i < 1 ? visibleUrl : unescapedUrl.substring(i);}}">

    <!-- Build the result data structure.-->
    <input type="hidden" id="url" data-attr="{value:unescapedUrl}" />

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <div data-if="Vars.richSnippet" data-attr="0"
            data-body="render('thumbnail',richSnippet,{url:unescapedUrl,target:target})"></div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">

          <!-- Append results within the table cell.-->
          <div class="gs-title">
            <a class="gs-title" data-attr="{href:'linkdetails2.php?url='+unescapedUrl+'?nome='+html(title),target:target}"
              data-body="html(title)"></a>
          </div>
```

The problem is in the last lines, this:

```
<a class="gs-title" data-attr="{href:'linkdetails2.php?url='+unescapedUrl+'?nome='+html(title),target:target}"
              data-body="html(title)"></a>
```

even if it renders right (the title is correctly displayed), when clicked (the target page in this case was: twitter.com/#!/asd) goes to this:

```
http://www.asd.com/linkdetails2.php?url=http://twitter.com/#!/asd?nome=[object DocumentFragment]
```

as you can see, the "html(title)", passed by "nome" isn't what i was expecting, but: [object DocumentFragment]

Is there a solution?

Thanks everyone

Comment: this does not look like a javascipt issue, whatever you use to render the results page doesn't render html(title) correctly..